# choose the complete metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

let $d(x,y)$  be the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

which of the following metric spaces is complete   ?

1. $\mathbb{Q}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$  with the metric $d(x,y)$
2. $(0,\infty) \times [0,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with the metric $d(x,y)$
3. $[0,1] \times  [0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$  with the metric $d''(x,y) = \min \{1,d(x,y)\}$.
4. none of these

my attempts ; i know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a complete metric space so $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is also not a complete metric space ..so option $1$ is not true...and for option $2$

....$d(x,y)$ may or may not be complete metric space. suppose i take

$d(x,y)= |e^x - e^y|$ which is not complete

now the for option $3$.. $d''(x,y) = \min\{1,d(x,y)\} = 1$   is  complete space

as every Cauchy sequence is constant so it is convergent. so   the correct

answer is option $3$ that $d''(x,y) = \min\{1,d(x,y)\}$  is complete metric space.

is my answer is correct or not ...pliz verified and tell me the solution . i would be more thankful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A subspace of a complete metric space is complete if and only of it is a closed subset of the whole space. Therefore, 1. and 2. are false.

The third option is also false. The sequence $\left(0,1-\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent.

Therefore, the correct option is 4.

Comment: suppose if i take n  →∞ , then the sequence will  (0,1).... im not getting the third option ,,that is  given that d"(x,y) = min(1,d(x,y)}....here how can i  colloboarate  with (0,1-1/n),,,i mean what is the relation ?@jose carlos  Santos

Comment: @lomberlego (0,1) does *not* belong to the space mentioned in 3.

Comment: [0,1]  contain (0,1),,,@jose  Carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego Again, $(0,1)\notin[0,1]\times[0,1)$.

Comment: i was thinking a lot,, as from my  view ... it will be (0,1)∈ [0,1] ×[0,1) = [0,1]..... but  why (0,1) is not belong  can u elaborate some hints ?@jose carlo santos

Comment: @lomberlego Because $1\notin[0,1)$.

Comment: ok  now i got.it @ jose carlos santos  ...one last doubt,, suppose the space given  is [0,1]×[0,1]  then it will  form a complete metric space...Am i right or wrong ?

Comment: @lomberlego Yes, it will.

Comment: thanks a lots @ jose carlos santos  i will marked  as an accepted answer and vote up now ..

Comment: @lomberlego Thank you.